# Cannot change stroke width in svg path

Tags: svg

```html
<svg id="mainwindow" width="360" height="780">
<path d="M 148.5 600 L 148.5 570 C 148.5 555 211.5 555 211.5 570 L 211.5 600 Z" fill="brown" stroke="black" stroke-width="10"/>
</svg>
```

The stroke width cannot be changed to 10px or any other value. If I put 0 it still displays a 1px stroke. But I can remove stroke by setting the stroke to none.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/st8u9wy4/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself

Comment: I have added a fiddle to try it. It might be due to the browser I think.

Comment: Replacing the character between stroke="black" and stroke-width="10" that looks like a space with a space fixes it for me.

Comment: Thanks that fixes it. It seem to have a nbsp in between